# Web Scraping data with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Hello I am scraping this page https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/china/super-league-2016/beijing-guoan-henan-jianye/S49KzkvO/ I have to scraper these data
[image]

```
Country = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/section/ul[1]/li[3]/a").text
leagueseason = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/section/header/h1/a").text
Home = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/section/ul[2]/li[1]/h2/a").text
Away = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/section/ul[2]/li[3]/h2/a").text
```

I tried with these XPATH but I would adapt with a more specific XPath, because that could be change. Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the `innerText` of the elements you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  - **China**:

    ```
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.list-breadcrumb li:nth-child(3) a"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
    ```
  - **Super League 2016**:

    ```
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1.wrap-section__header__title>a"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
    ```
  - **Beijing Guoan**:

    ```
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.list-details>li:first-child h2.list-details__item__title>a"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
    ```
  - **Henan Jianye**:

    ```
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.list-details>li:nth-child(3) h2.list-details__item__title>a"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
    ```
- Using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) and *text* attribute:

  - **China**:

    ```
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='list-breadcrumb']//following::li[3]//a"))).text)
    ```
  - **Super League 2016**:

    ```
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h1[@class='wrap-section__header__title']/a"))).text)
    ```
  - **Beijing Guoan**:

    ```
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='list-details']//following::li[1]//h2/a"))).text)
    ```
  - **Henan Jianye**:

    ```
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='list-details']//following::li[2]//h2/a"))).text)
    ```
  - **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

    ```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)